# Need help to configure API connect with datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I wanted to secure my microservices built in api connect using Oauth for that i need to use datapower as authorization server.
Is there any step by step document/example to configure API connect to use Datapower Gateway API gateway.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling and Configuring DataPower worked for me it concludes that there was a problem with initial configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Using the API Designer from API Connect, you can create OAuth-based security for your microservice app that uses DataPower as the OAuth provider.  Are you familiar with the API Designer and the API Connect toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 is supported by the Micro Gateway only from version 5.0.3 and onwards but as you have DataPower you are fine. The interface/GUI is much better though in later versions of v5.

Did you see this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_apionprem_security_OAuth.html

Or this:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_sec_api_config_scheme_oauth_endpoint.html

Check out Lab 4 here:
https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/pot-onprem-docs/tree/master/lab-guide

The Lab software/setup is also found in that GitHub account!

Comment: thanks for the help but the problem was in the initial configuration of DataPower. just installed and configured DataPower again and it worked.